# Change the url in codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, url, routes

My url like

> http://localhost/message/Welcome/index

But i like to show

> hhttp://localhost/message/index

remove the controller name

My routes

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['index'] = 'welcome/index';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

And try this one

> $route['message/send'] = "message/welcome/send";

My htaccess

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
```

Please help me to remove the controller in the middle of url .
Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: It looks like your using the htaccess from application folder incorrect. You should place new htaccess in main directory here are some examples https://github.com/wolfgang1983/htaccess_for_codeigniter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that simply using your `.htaccess` file. Add the following rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/Welcome /$1 [R=301,L]
```

That will remove `/welcome` from your URL using a 301 redirection. Leaving you with: http://localhost/message/index

Make sure you clear your cache **before** testing this.